# How to append CharStreams?

Tags: java, guava

When I use the object `OutputSupplier`, adding the first line (`CharStreams.write`) is executed correctly. But then calling `CharStreams.write` again throws an `IOException`.

Is this the correct behavior of the object? If so, how can you append a `String` to the supplier object without closing the inline stream?

```
...

final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

OutputSupplier<OutputStreamWriter> writerSupplier = CharStreams.newWriterSupplier(new OutputSupplier<OutputStream>() {
    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutput() throws IOException {
        return process.getOutputStream();
    }
}, Charsets.UTF_8);
// ok
CharStreams.write(someCommand, writerSupplier);
...
// IOException
CharStreams.write(otherCommand, writerSupplier);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely expected behavior.

`CharStreams.write` with an `OutputSupplier` opens the output stream, writes, and closes it.  That's part of the point.  Presumably, `Process.getOutputStream()` doesn't let you open and close more than once.

Either do all the writes at once, or more likely, don't use `CharStreams.write` and deal with closing the stream yourself.

Comment: Do you plan to add append method to CharStreams? Or is it contradicts the ideology of Supplier class?

Comment: The whole point of the `Supplier` class is to open, operate on, and close the output without you having to remember to do any of those things, but closing the output is incompatible with appending -- so, yeah, it's not possible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what if the OutputSupplier opens the file in append mode using `new FileOutputStream(file, true)`. It should work then, shouldn't it? (Granted, the performance will be awful, probably)